# ES6 modules: React accordion circular dependency

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

For building an ES6 Accordion menu with theoretically an infinite number of recursive levels, I would have two React components, each importing one another.
Simplified snippet:

1) Unordered AccordionList component:

```
render(){
    let AccordionItems = this.props.list.map((item) => { 
        <AccordionItem item={item} />
    }); 
    return ( <ul class='accordion-menu'> {AccordionItems} </ul> ); 
}
```

2) Items, each of them requiring a nested ul (extra logic omitted):

```
render(){
    //Extract list from passed in item prop 
    <li>
        submenu 
        <AccordionList list={list} />
    </li>
}
```

Is this sort of circular dependency bad practice when using Babel?
What is the general workaround if so?

Comment: You could pass all the `<AccordionItem>` as children to `<AccordionList>`.

Comment: @FelixKling If it is a recursive tree (nested json arrays) where every nested list is a 'children' attribute on every list item, how will I achieve that? Should I create a closure within the render method? Btw has you name changed? Wasn't it Felix King or was that my imagination?

Comment: All you'd need to do is move the `this.props.list.map` call outside. E.g. `<AccordionList list={list} />` simply becomes `<AccordionList>{list.map(item => <AccordionItem item={item} />)}</AccordionList>`. And yes, that must have been your imagination. That was always my name :)

Comment: Although, as long as you are not trying to access the class at import time, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok haha that's silly sorry man... Ok, I'll proceed with the current code then, I just need the default component instances when building the accordion. I got a bit confused over your code snippet because it seems to apply only on the first level but not on the recursiveness i.e. every item has in turn a 'children' attribute, representing a nested <AccordionList /> within the item. I could probably just place them in one module too, but would rather prefer not to.

Comment: Still, regarding your question: no, that's not the kind of circular dependency between modules that is bad or does not work.

Comment: @Bergi sorry for the late reply and thanks for your confirmation!